# Can't assign texture to scene child node

Tags: swift, while-loop, textures, children

I am trying to iterate over all the children (SKSpriteNode) of my game scene that have a certain name made out of a counter (that increases with the iteration) and a string common to all of them, and assign them a texture (with a filename made out of a number stored in an array and the name of a fruit common to all of the children).

I have the following while loop.

when I run the game in my simulator, it seems to find all the children fine (I have a print statement that prints found child whenever the child.name coincides with what I'm looking for) and the count increases as predicted as well, however the texture is not assigned and the children remain looking like single colour squares. I added the children manually through the spritekit interface, I didn't generate them programmatically, if that makes any difference.

```
    while count < fruits.count {
        let children = self.children

        for  case let child as SKSpriteNode in children  {

            if child.name == "option\(count)" {

                child.texture == SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(fruits[count])oranges")

            }

        }
        // assign texture to button (enumerate?)

        count = count + 1
    }
```

Anyone has any idea of what's going on?

Many thanks!

Comment: You used the "==" when trying to assign the child's texture which results in a boolean data type. You need to assign the child's texture to the SKTexture using one equal sign (=)

Comment: Oh my god, how did I not notice that! thank you so much, that's such a dumb mistake! cheers mate!